# Gameport to USB adapters for joysticks

Tags: windows-7, usb, game-controller

I have a Microsoft Sidewinder Precision Pro joystick that I would liek to use with my Windows 7 PC, but I need some kind of adapter that will allow me to use USB instead of the gameport adapter that the joystick has.

Where can I buy something like this?

What are some experiences you have with this or other joysticks using adapters for modern games like Battlefield etc.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: @Caltor I ended up buying a new USB joystick

Answer (score 2):

First, according to the [Windows 7 Compatibility pages](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=Microsoft%20SideWinder%20Precision%20Pro%20Game%20Controller&v=Microsoft&uid=326-00105&pf=1&pi=7&c=Mice%2C%20Keyboards%20%26%20Input%20Devices&sc=Game%20Controllers&os=32-bit), that joystick *will work* in Windows 7 without additional drivers.

Additionally, you can get Game Port to USB adapters.  A company named [Logilink makes one](http://www.logilink.org/showproduct/UA0052B.htm) (I'm sure there are others as well).

[image: Logilink Game port to USB adapter]

You could also get yourself a [cheap Windows 7 compatible sound card](http://www.startech.com/product/PCISOUND4CH-4-Channel-PCI-Sound-Card-with-AC97-3D-Audio-Effects) that contains a game port.

[image: Cheap Soundcard with Game Port]

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but for future readers/friends of the best joysticks
ever in existence:

For the Gameport-Joysticks

- Sidewinder 3D Pro
- Sidewinder 3D Precision Pro
- Sidewinder Force Feedback

an usual Gameport->Usb-Adapter won't do, because MS utilized
non-standard pin-usage, to allow for more Buttons/Axes.
After MS dropped the Gameport support in Vista, only few
companies (e.g. Creative) made their own stacks/drivers.
To my knowledge none of those work in 64-Bit.

The only solution is to build/order a sw3dprousb:
https://code.google.com/p/sw3dprousb/

For ForceFeedback-effects, a fork named adapt-ffb-joy exists:
https://code.google.com/p/adapt-ffb-joy/

---

Update Aug '19:
Apparently you can order the project in kit-/finished from this page

http://www.iowajohnsons.com/FFBVert/FAQ.php

(scroll down to "HOW DO I GET AN ADAPTER?")

Answer (score 0):

don't bother.... buy a new gamepad/joystick. Windows 7 does not support this device and there is no type of driver for them. It sucks but you will save a lot of stress, time, and a little money by just buying a new gamebad.